# Parcelize MaterialTheme's Colors, Typography and Shapes

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, material-components-android

I would like to let Activity B to adopt Activity A's MaterialTheme, to do so, I wanted to parcelize the 3 params, and send them over through a `Bundle`. It seems `Colors` is easy since we can convert the rgb values to primitive, but the other two is pretty complicated to parcelize.

Question -
Is it even possible parcelize `Typography` and `Shapes` without losing information? Or are there any other ways to let B knows the MaterialTheme used in A?